# Combine value of 2 array based on servername

Tags: powershell

Below are the 2 tables i have which i got from query

Table -1

```
Servername              Type max avg
lnx0401.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  100 40
lnx0402.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  99  30
lnx0576.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  34  3
lnx0577.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  94  8
lnx0578.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  99  21
```

Table -2

```
Servername              Type Count
lnx0401.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  86
lnx0402.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  42
```

Output should be like

```
Servername             Type max avg count
lnx0401.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  100 40 86
lnx0402.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  99  30 42
lnx0576.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  34  3  0
lnx0577.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  94  8  0
lnx0578.ch3.prod.i.com  AS  99  21 0
```

have to match data of Table -2 with Table -1 and if server present at Table - 1 the need to pick the count from table -2 and create final table else will put 0 against count.

Please let me know how to do this

tried but confused

```
$hashB=@{}
foreach($records in $data_2)
{
    $hashB[$records.servername] = $records
}

$data_1 | foreach{
    
    $record = $_
    $other = $hashB[$record.servername]

    [pscustomobject]@{ServerName=$_.servername
                 RoleType=$_.RoleType
                 CPUMax = $_.cpumax
                 CPUAvg = $_.cpuavg
                 PeakCount = $other.peakcount}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without installing any module with

```
$table3 = $table1 | ForEach-Object  {
    $server = $_.Servername
    $_ | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Count'; Expression = {[int]($table2 | Where-Object {$_.Servername -eq $server}).Count}}
}

# output on screen
$table3 | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$table3 | Export-Csv -Path 'table3.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen

```
Servername             Type max avg Count
----------             ---- --- --- -----
lnx0401.ch3.prod.i.com AS   100 40  86   
lnx0402.ch3.prod.i.com AS   99  30  42   
lnx0576.ch3.prod.i.com AS   34  3   0    
lnx0577.ch3.prod.i.com AS   94  8   0    
lnx0578.ch3.prod.i.com AS   99  21  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. exactly looking for this but one small issue. in the output, instead of Count =0 it is coming blank.

Comment: @EmptyCoder You can cast the result in the Expression to `[int]`. This will force a `0` when blank. (edited in the code). What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: worked exactly. thanks again.using powershell 5.1.14409.1018

Answer (score 0):

use the join-object module it, it will allow for the merge of the 2 arrays with out any loops. In the example I am using csv from import you dont have to you can just use the arrays. Example

Install-Module Join-object

$test = Import-Csv C:\Temp\test1.csv
$test2 = Import-Csv C:\Temp\test2.csv

Join-Object -Left $test -LeftJoinProperty Servername -Right $test2 -RightJoinProperty servername -RightProperties count

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/2.0.1